# How to get perfect audio timing

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, timing

I am trying to loop beats with this:

```
while(True):
    t0 = time.time() #start timing

    print(c) #c is the position of the pattern (e.g. kick = [1, 0, 1, 0])

    if self.patterns['kick'][c] == 1:
        channel1.play(kick)
    if self.patterns['snare'][c] == 1:
        channel2.play(snare)

    c = (c+1)%l #increase counter/jump to start

    d = int((2400-1000*(time.time()-t0))/l) #calculates the time delay (whole loop is  2400 milliseconds); l is the pattern-lenght
    pygame.time.delay(d)            
    print (time.time() - t0)
```

As you can see I measure the time of the whole process and then correct my time delay appropriate. But with this I still get +-20ms lag.

Does anyone know a good solution to time audio playback in python perfectly?
Or can you give me suggestions how to make my code more efficient to get the minimum lag?

Thanks!

Comment: How accurate do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Getting this kind of accuracy (sub 20ms) will be challenging I think.

One source of problems may be using `time.time()`, which is returning a count of seconds as a large floating point number.  Floating point numbers are not particularly accurate in some situations, and perhaps the finer points of the time amount are being rounded/truncated away.

You could try using the pygame time functions, which return the time-since-started as a integer count of milliseconds.  This will remove any sort of floating point rounding/truncation issue.

```
while ( True ):
    time_start = pygame.time.get_ticks() # start timing

    # pattern_cursor is the position of the pattern (e.g. kick = [1, 0, 1, 0])
    #print( pattern_cursor )  

    if self.patterns['kick'][pattern_cursor] == 1:
        channel1.play(kick)
    if self.patterns['snare'][pattern_cursor] == 1:
        channel2.play(snare)

    # increase counter/jump to start
    pattern_cursor = ( pattern_cursor+1 ) % pattern_length 

    # calculates the time delay (whole loop is  2400 milliseconds)
    time_now   = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    time_delay = 2400-1000 * ( time_now - start_time ) / pattern_length 
    pygame.time.delay( time_delay )            
    #print( time_delay )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using for loop for each list of pattern and delay the note play based on the position of the "1" in the loop. What I mean is try to delay all notes together at once. And then by the last note start another grouped delay as done before.